# select case not working #1064

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm having an issue with this

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN QuantityPart =< Threshold
               THEN (Threshold - QuantityPart) + Threshold
       END as RecommendedReorderQuantity, *
FROM parts, stock
```

can anyone help?

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN QuantityPart =< Threshold 
            THEN (Threshold - QuantityPart) + Threshold 
       END as RecommendedReorderQuantity 
FROM parts INNER JOIN stock 
        ON parts.PartID = stock.PartID
```

Comment: What's the exact problem?

Answer (score 3):

the `*` should come first before your `CASE` sattement, one more thing, it should be

`<=` **not** `=<`

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN QuantityPart <= Threshold 
            THEN (Threshold - QuantityPart) + Threshold 
       END as RecommendedReorderQuantity 
FROM parts, stock
```

As a sidenote, the query produces cartesian product. If that's not what you want tthen you need to supply for linking condition, ex

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN QuantityPart <=  Threshold 
            THEN (Threshold - QuantityPart) + Threshold 
       END as RecommendedReorderQuantity 
FROM parts INNER JOIN stock 
        ON parts.columnName = stock.columnName
```

where `columnName` is the column that defines their relationship.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=&lt; Threshold THEN (Threshold - QuantityPart) + Threshold ' at line 2

Comment: is appearing i think theres something wrong with the case statement

Comment: @PreetSangha yes `:D` see this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8add1/7 uncomment the firstline

Comment: @NaivenDhali use `<=` not `=<`

Comment: SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN QuantityPart =< Threshold 
            THEN (Threshold - QuantityPart) + Threshold 
       END as RecommendedReorderQuantity 
FROM parts INNER JOIN stock 
        ON parts.PartID = stock.PartID

Comment: did you change `=<` into `<=` in your case statement?

Comment: can you show sample records of `parts` and `stock` with your desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Also, it is a safe practice to specify the else condition, even if trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Replace =< with <=

SELECT
CASE WHEN QuantityPart <= Threshold
               THEN (Threshold - QuantityPart) + Threshold
       END as RecommendedReorderQuantity, *
FROM parts, stock